# Is there any Technology like WebRTC that supports all platforms and browsers?

Tags: streaming, webrtc

I want to develop a project for conference between doctor and patient but admin can also join. Each person should have options for privacy.

I'm looking for a technology has all ability same as WebRTC but should be supports all platforms. It may be either open source or paid service.
Please suggest the best ?

Comment: Hopefully only back to IE9+...